# General approach to solve some counting problems

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, combinatorics-on-words

I have heard that there is a general approach using generating functions to solve the following type of problems: find the number of words of length $8$ made from letters $A, B, C, D, E$ such that letters $A$ and $B$ appear at most once and $C, D$ at least once.

Could anyone explain the approach or give a reference to book or source to read about it?

Comment: $(1+x)^2(x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots)^2(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots)$ and look at $8!$ times the coefficient of $x^8$.  As for a book, try [generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).

Comment: Could you elaborate on how did you find those series?

Comment: Because order matters, we want each time we multiply through with a specific choice from each parenthetical section to represent a multinomial coefficient, for example choosing $x,1,x^3/3!,x^3/3!,x$ would correspond to having one $a$, no $b$'s, three $c$'s, three $d$'s, and one $e$, and these can be arranged in a string in $\frac{8!}{1!0!3!3!1!}$ many ways.  "At most once" implies either zero times or one time, hence $(1+x)$ (*the $1$ corresponding to zero times, the $x$ corresponding to one time*).  Similarly, at least once corresponds to $(x+x^2/2!+\dots)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for you concise explanation. Now I see the  approach.